# Flume ignores filtering key words in flume conf

Tags: configuration, config, flume, flume-ng

I am using `flume` to import TWITTER DATA.
I added the following line to my `flume` conf:

`TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.keywords = hadoop, big data, analytics, bigdata, cloudera, data science, data scientiest, business intelligence, mapreduce, data warehouse, data warehousing, mahout, hbase, nosql, newsql, businessintelligence, cloudcomputing`

but `flume` ignores this line!
`Flume` always imports ALL DATA from twitter, not specified and filtered through our key words.

How can I get the filtering to work?

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link: https://github.com/cloudera/cdh-twitter-example/tree/master/flume-sources

Use this class:

> com.cloudera.flume.source.TwitterSource

By the way, recompile the JAR, dont use the prebuilt version :)

EDIT: To recompile, follow section 1 of the link:

To build the flume-sources JAR, from the root of the git repository:

```
 cd flume-sources  
 mvn package
 cd ..
```

This will generate a file called flume-sources-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar in the target directory.

Comment: how can I recompile it? and WHICH .jar should I recompile?

Comment: If you have made any changes to the program, you can build that in eclipse and use it instead of the original jar.